С/С++. Замена переменных массивом
Прошу поделиться своими мыслями.
Предположим, внутри функции у нас есть 5 локальных переменных типа int. На сколько неэффективно по скорости работы (доступа к элементам массива) будет замена их на одну переменную-массив с размерностью 5, т.е. int[5]?

Скорее всего ни на сколько. Ухудшится вряд ли, раз уж все индексы будут известны во время компиляции. Улучшаться не из-за чего...

Похоже, вы правы. Проверил в отладчике. При включении оптимизации ассемблерный код становится практически идентичный. Спасибо.

Локальные переменные расположены на стеке, поэтому с точки зрения размещения реальных данных ничего не изменится, особенно если исходные переменные были определены друг за другом.
В первую очередь программу надо сделать понятной для человека. Т.е. как минимум дать понятные имена переменным. Если они задают разные сущности, имена, скорее всего, должны серьёзно отличаться. Если при этом они используются совместно, то стоит рассмотреть вариант выделения их в самостоятельную структуру/класс. Для действительно однотипных данных, формирующих некоторую последовательность/группу, имеет смысл использовать массив (или другой подходящий контейнер) с единым именем.
